# Php Eloquent Enumeration

Tags: php, enumeration

Is anyone familiar with working with this library: https://github.com/eloquent/enumeration

I am having trouble converting the instance of the constant back to the constant value.

```
class TestEnum extends AbstractEnumeration
{
    const THING1 = 'test1';
    const THING2 = 'test2';
}

class DoStuff 
{
    public function action(TestEnum $test)
    {
        if($test === 'test1') {
            echo 'THIS WORKS';
        }
    }
}

$enumTest = TestEnum::THING1();
$doStuff = new DoStuff();
$doStuff->action($enumTest);
```

My goal is to have the method action print 'THIS WORKS'. Because $test is an instance of TestEnum, this would not evaluate to true.

Comment: [This works](https://eval.in/183142), although I'm not sure it's what you're after.

Comment: I know that without the parenthesis it works, but that's not quite what I am after. The goal is to keep the type hinting in action(). Thanks anyhow! @scrowler

Comment: Yeah - the parenthesis is telling PHP to look for a function though...

Comment: With the library, the parenthesis means that TestEnum::THING1() is an instance of TestEnum class. If you're using phpstorm it'll freak out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but there are two problems:

1. Case matters. `Thing1` != `THING1`
2. `$test`, when treated as a string, evaluates to its key `THING1`. You want its value `$test->value()`

---

#### Example:

```
class TestEnum extends AbstractEnumeration
{
    const THING1 = 'test1';
    const THING2 = 'test2';
}

class DoStuff
{
    public function action(TestEnum $test)
    {
        if($test->value() === 'test1') {
            echo 'THIS WORKS';
        }
    }
}

$enumTest = TestEnum::THING1();
$doStuff = new DoStuff();
$doStuff->action($enumTest);
```

#### Output:

```
THIS WORKS
```

Comment: The case thing was a typo. Thanks for catching that. So I understand that the ->value() part is my goal. Is that a built in php function? 

In my case, if I were to write out a separate function to determine the value, the code will get messy and excessive. @derp

Comment: jk. just found it in the documentation. Thanks!